# From where does Jquery timer plugin fetches the current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timer, countdowntimer

I am using a jquery timer plugin from [here](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html)

The method takes a finalDate to countdown to

finalDate is the target date till when the timer will countdown to.

My question is

From where does the method fetches the current time & computes the interval to countdown to. Is it the client's system time?

As the plugin is only recognizing the next day date, if given today's date it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the 12 hour format from the server wherein I should be getting the 24 hour format. Works fine now.